# Why is the compiler not complaining about an additional ',' in Array or Object Initializers?

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, c#-4.0

Using simple type like

```
class A {
  public int X, Y;
}
```

with object intializers, one can write

```
var a = new A { X=0, Y=0 };
```

*But* the following is also accepted by the compiler:

```
var a = new A { X=0, Y=0, }; // notice the additional ','
```

Same for `int[] v = new int[] { 1, 2, };`

This looks a bit strange ... Did they forgot to reject the additional ',' in the compiler or is there a deeper meaning behind this?

Comment: They didn't forget anything, it's a deliberate part of the language design. (In the Microsoft C#3 spec it's spelled out in section 7.5.10.2 for object initializers and section 7.5.10.3 for collection initializers.)

Comment: FYI, this trick also works for enums.  And we also allow a superfluous semicolon to follow a class declaration, because some C++ programmers are in the habit of typing one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't anything deep, it's a common thing accepted by compilers of many (but not all) languages. This makes doing lists easier:

```
var a = new A {
    X = 0,
    Y = 0,
};
```

When you want to add `Z = 0`, you don't need to edit the previous line to add a comma. This improves source code control deltas, because there is only one new line instead of one new line and one changed line.

Comment: Surely you would add it as `Z = 0,` ;)

Comment: Being punsished by the C/C++ compiler over and over again when doing this wrong, I now feel sick about these programmer-friendly simplifications ;)

Answer (score 1):

This also simplifies an implementation of code generators. They don't have to check the last comma.